# How to create a thick provisioned virtual disk file with mke2fs / fallocate?

Tags: debian

I currently make virtual disks specifically for storage size quotas.  I can make a 10GB disk as exampled:

```bsh
touch myShare-10G
truncate -s 10G myShare-10G
mke2fs -t ext4 -F myShare-10G
fallocate -l 10G myShare-10G
```

```bsh
ls -s myShare-10G --block-size=G
```

shows it as 11GB used.

After copying 5GB worth of data, the file size still properly stays at 11GB.

**My issue is that after deleting that 5GB worth of data, the file size drops down to 6GB, rather than staying at the  11GB size.**

How can I keep my virtual disk "thick" provisioned (meaning, the file size stays fixed regardless of the content inside)?

Comment: How do you mount the virtual disk?

Comment: just the standard command line mount: mount myShare-10G /mnt/myShare-10G

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One easy way to do it is make the backing device non-discard-able. You get this for free with LVM volumes backed by HDDs and using those as virtual disk drives for your VM. Using raw block devices is also a common recommendation for best performance:

> https://www.linux-kvm.org/page/Tuning_KVM
>
> QEMU supports a wide variety for storage formats and back-ends. Easiest to use are the raw and qcow2 formats, but for the best performance it is best to use a raw partition. You can create either a logical volume or a partition [...]

However once you move to SSD storage, naturally it will discard again. Same would happen with LVM thin provisioning volumes, even if it was HDD (`man lvmthin`).

In that case, you just have to tell the VM to not allow that. In case of qemu/KVM, this can be done with the `discard=ignore` parameter. I assume that other virtualization solutions have a similar setting somewhere.

From qemu manpage:

```
           "discard=discard"
               discard is one of "ignore" (or "off") or "unmap" (or "on")
               and controls whether "discard" (also known as "trim" or
               "unmap") requests are ignored or passed to the filesystem.
               Some machine types may not support discard requests.
```

For sake of clear intentions, it does not hurt to specify even if discards are currently not possible in your configuration.

---

On a sidenote, your setup commands can be shorter:

```
# create a new allocated file
fallocate -l 10G myShare-10G
# format it without discarding it
mke2fs -t ext4 -E nodiscard myShare-10G
```

That should give you the same result as your 4 command chain above.

You only need -F if you're overwriting existing filesystems and don't want the prompt. For a new file, it should not be necessary.

Comment: Thank you for the QEMU/KVM idea, but even though I want to create virtual disks, I am not using a Hypervisor in my scenario.  I just want a limited storage pool where the whole space is allocated so I don't over-provision my physical disk.  I'd prefer setting these shares up with native debian tools, if possible.

Comment: @R.StackUser sorry, I was thinking of virtual machines somehow. But you meant regular loop devices. Don't know if `losetup` can be told to ignore discard somehow. `cryptsetup` is one of the few that does that by default, if encryption is an option for you. Then there's `qemu-nbd --connect /dev/nbd0 --format=raw --discard=ignore --detect-zeroes=off filesystem.img` which creates an NBD device instead of loop device. That works (I guess) but it's not great. I'd still go with LVM volumes...

Comment: That said if you don't mount with `discard` flag and don't run `fstrim` (also look out for system wide timers) it should just not discard anything, even though there's nothing to strictly prevent it from happening.

Comment: The nodiscard flag was the key, it is now keeping the same size as required, thanks again for the help.